# Shorter code for copy x elements between char arrays

Tags: c++

Does here exist a shorter code for this?

```
unsigned char* msg = new unsigned char(msgLen + 1);
for (int i = 0; i < msgLen; i++) {
    msg[i] = (buffer[index + i]);
}
msg[msgLen] = 0;
```

I am looking for something like:

*take **start nth element** and **end nth element** from **buffer** and **copy** them to **msg***

I cannot use `std::vector`, because I do this stuff on platforms where the compiler doesn't have `std::vector`.

Comment: Can you use `std::copy`?

Comment: Can you use [`std::memmove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove) from `<cstring>`?

Comment: `I do this stuff on platforms where the compiler doesn't have std::vector.` Then use a non-standard implementation of vector instead.

Comment: I cannot. But I probably can write own similiar function which does same thing. But I don't know how to copy nths elements. I can use `memcpy`.

Comment: You show you are shifting elements down by one -- is this intentional? If so, just `memcpy (msg, &buffer[1], msgLen)` -- which will copy the nul-terminating character if `buffer` holds a nul-terminated string, otherwise use `msgLen - 1` and manually nul-terminate at `msg[msgLen-1] = 0;`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::copy`.

```
std::copy(buffer + index, buffer + index + msgLen, msg);
msg[msgLen] = 0;
```

If not maybe `std::memcpy` (from C).

```
memcpy(msg, buffer + index, msgLen);
msg[msgLen] = 0;
```

Comment: You need to subtract `index` from `msgLen` otherwise you are copying beyond the end of `buffer` with `memcpy` (and likely the same with `std::copy`).